# Integrate with the Windows Shell

Tags: windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

OK,

I want to create a windows shell extention that sits in the file menu much like the "Tortorise SVN" menu.

Does anyone know where I'd begin, a good article, or what interfaces to implement?

Thanks!

Comment: Trust me: tags on stackoverflow are for categorization.  They shouldn't tell a story or summarize the question.  See this faq item:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229784/tips-for-effectively-tagging-questions

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell what you edited, the page didn't say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward actually. It's about a 3-4 step process. You didn't specify what language you were using.

Here's how to do it in native code:

http://www.kbcafe.com/articles/HowTo.Shell.pdf

Here's how to do it with .NET. Note that it is essentially the same as doing it with native code.

http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions

Comment: I would like to write the add-in in Managed Code, but I'm prepared to resurrect my C++ skills to write the add-in code.  Thanks for the help, it was much needed.

Comment: Only .NET 4 is actually supported for shell extensions. Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ah... Shell extensions... they can be a real pain in the butt if they're complicated, but you can do so much neat stuff. A great place to start is Mike Dunn's [Complete Idiot's Guide To Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx) on codeproject.com.

Comment: Mike Dunn's articles are great. Can't believe I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an O'Reilly book called [VB Shell Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926706) which goes into the API's in some depth.  As the title suggests, it's aimed at Visual BASIC, but the API's are exposed through COM and the techniques discussed in the book are applicable for pretty much anything that supports COM.  A quick look on Amazon.com suggests you can probably pick up a secondhand copy for a few dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid codeproject (for kids, full of bugs) and read the complete doc of MSDN on SNE.